# the following function : $(t,x)\mapsto tx$ from $[0,1]\times A$ to $X$ is continous

Tags: continuity, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A$ be a nonempty closed subsets of $X$.

Consider the following function: $(t,x)\mapsto tx$ from $[0,1]\times A$ to $X$.
Show that it is continous function:

My effort:

Let $(a,x) $ and $(b,y)$ in $[0,1]\times A$, we have:
$$
\|ax-by\|\leq \|ax-ay\|+\|ay-by\|=|a|\|x-y\|+|a-b|\|y\|
$$
then, if  $(a,x) $ tends towards $(b,y) $ we have:
$$
\|ax-by\|\to 0
$$
Then this function is continous.

This is true.?

Comment: Looks correct, but it's better and more clear to take actual sequences and show sequential continuity.

Comment: Yes this is fine, as the above commenter said use sequences. Also, this does not require the space to be Bamach, all normas spaces are topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ a normed vector space (not necessarily a Banach space) and the map 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f : [0,1] \times A & \to X \\
(\alpha, x) & \mapsto \alpha x 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $A\subset X$ is a non-empty closed subset of $X$. Then, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
||f(\alpha,x)-f(\beta, y)|| & =||\alpha x-\beta y|| \\
& =||\alpha x-\alpha y+ \alpha y-\beta y|| \\
& \leq ||\alpha x-\alpha y||+|| \alpha y-\beta y|| \\
& = |\alpha|\cdot ||x-y||+||y||\cdot|\alpha-\beta|
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Since $A$ is closed, then for every $x\in A$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset A$ that converges to $x$. Analogously, since $[0,1]$ is closed, then for every $\alpha \in A$ there exists a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}\subset [0,1]$ that converges to $\alpha$.

Hence, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can pick $y\in A\backslash \{0\}$ and $\beta\in [0,1]$ such than 
$$||x-y||\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2|\alpha|}, \quad |\alpha-\beta|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2||y||}$$
and the previous inequality is written as 
$$ ||f(\alpha,x)-f(\beta, y)|| \leq |\alpha|\cdot ||x-y||+||y||\cdot|\alpha-\beta|\leq |\alpha|\frac{\varepsilon}{2|\alpha|}+||y||\frac{\varepsilon}{2||y||} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$$

Observe that this argument does not hold when $\alpha=0$. However, we can write for this case 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
||f(\alpha,x)-f(\beta, y)|| & =||\alpha x-\beta y|| \\
& =||\alpha x-\beta x+ \beta x-\beta y|| \\
& = |\beta|\cdot ||x-y||+||x||\cdot|\alpha-\beta|
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and use an analogous argumentation.